# How to use the tags in my function scenario Cucumber.js?

Tags: javascript, protractor, bdd, cucumberjs

How to use the tags in my function scenario ?

How to know the scenario that calls my function ?

Actually I have one scenario :

```
Feature: create module feature
  As a admin
  I want to use create module

  @createModule
  Given I am logged as 'ADMIN'
    And I am on "/admin/create"
   Then The "book_id" field should be empty
```

I would like to use my tag @createModule in my function Then :

```
this.Then(/^The "?([^"]*)"? field should be empty$/, function (el) {

    if (myModule === @createModule) {
        ...
    } else if {
        ...
    }

    return main_po.checkIsEmptyElement(this, el);
});
```

I would like to get my tag @createModule, to specify the scenario called, or other alternative, I would like to know what scenarios call my function.

> Solved :

I added :

```
this.Before(function (scenario, callback) {
    var tags = scenario.getTags();

    this.current_module = tags[0].getName();

    callback();
});
```

and my function :

```
this.Then(/^The "?([^"]*)"? field should be empty$/, function (el) {

    if (this.current_module === @createModule) {
        ...
    } else if {
        ...
    }

    return main_po.checkIsEmptyElement(this, el);
});
```

Comment: This is an interesting use of tags, but dangerous: changing tags should not have an effect on the tests, they could be automatically generated, adapted to a different team, etc. Instead you should add "Given my task is createModule' and in the step you store the "createModule" in your world: this.current_module = module

Comment: I'm trying to implement something like this. May I know what is 'current_module' in you example?

Answer (score 0):

this is what i used for getting tags of feature or scenario for cucumber 3.0.7

```
let myTags = feature.pickle.tags;
    myTags.forEach(element => {
    logger.info(`My Tags: ${element.name}`);

});
```